# Format field if not all choices are chosen

Tags: list, json-formatting, choice-field

For my use case, I want to have an overview of finished tasks. One part of this list should be if all the responsabilities have been informed.
I'd like to make this a choice list, as it allows the users for easy (un-)check and the info is neatly grouped in one column.

My problem resides in checking if all the choices have been selected. As soon as one is unselected, it should be visible (f.e. making the line red, or changing another field).

Is there a way I can do this with formulas or JSON? formula's don't seem to allow for choices. JSON will only allow to check for one value of the choice not multiple at once?
PowerAutomate is out of the question in our environment.

Comment: Can you explain more about your requirements? Images/screenshots will help to understand/image what exactly you want. It might be possible with the JSON formatting.